# Passing argument by reference; does the function return type HAVE to be void?

Tags: c++, function, reference, return, pass-by-reference

I've recently started to learn C++ and now I'm learning about passing arguments to functions. Knowing there are two methods of doing so, I've made a simple code of doubling a number given by the user.

My first question is,
When passing an argument to a function through reference, MUST that function be a `void` type or can it be an `int` too?

I ask this question because most of the examples I've seen have been using void.

Second question is my code,

```
    #include <iostream>


    //using std::cout;
    //using std::cin;
    //using std::endl;


    using namespace std;


    int doubleByValue(int value){       //this is the function which takes the argumrnt passed down by main as a Value
        int Doubled;
        Doubled = value * value;

        return Doubled;
    }

    /*
    int doubleByReference(int &value){      //This is the function which takes the argument passed from main as a Reference
        value = value * value;

        return value;
    }
    */

    void doubleByReference(int &value){     //This is the function which takes the argument passed from main as a Reference
        value = value * value;

    }


    int main(){
        cout << "In this program we would be doubling the values entered by the user" << endl;
        cout << "using the two methods of passing arguments, through value and by reference." << endl;


        int Number = 0;
        cout << "Please enter a Number: ";
        cin >> Number;


        cout << endl << "Number doubled after passed by Value: " << doubleByValue(Number) << endl;
        cout << endl << "Number doubled after passed by Reference: " << doubleByReference(Number) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

My top method, i.e the passing an argument through value method works completely fine.

But, I've used two methods to pass an argument by reference, by which the type `int` function works completely fine (This is the one I've commented) but I get a ton of errors or warnings for the second one. Why is that happening? because there's not much of a difference between the two I really don't understand how could there be such big errors or warnings for this.

I notice the program still runs so I'm guessing it's just warnings.

Comment: You get a ton of errors because `std::cout << doubleByReference(value)` attempts to use the return value of that function call, but the function returns `void`. You could have shown that error with far less code than you posted. And, to answer the question, yes, you can define that function to return `int` if you want to, as your commented-out version does.

Comment: The types you pass to a function are completely unrelated to the functions return type.

Comment: Maybe, I'm nitpicking but: `doubleBy`... is a bit misleading. Actually, `value * value` returns squared value, `value + value` would return double value. (Now, where that has been mentioned I feel better...) ;-)

Comment: Bit of trivia: the expression `cin >> Number` invokes [`basic_istream& operator>>(int& value)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt), which is a function that takes its argument by reference and that returns something other than `void`. So as for your first question... you actually answered it in your own example. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters of a function and the return type are not related.

The warnings you get come from `std::cout .... << doubleByReference(value)`, because `std::cout` expects a value, but that function returns nothing.

Comment: is there a way to fix that? I could still use the int type but I want to know what i could do to fix that warning. I wouldn't want to risk anyone thinking that's a code with errors.

Comment: Just add `return value`, as you did with the other version.

Comment: so, it DOESN'T always have to be void. just that all the examples i've seen shows them using voids.

Comment: The point of passing by reference is that the value can change inside the function, and remains changed for the code after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

Example of illegal functions signatures

```
 void function(void& arg)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Example of a legal function signature

The function below is return void* pointer which can point to any data type in memory. so here the return type is not void but rather a pointer to any type here specified using void*

```
void* function(void*& arg)
{
...
}
```

here the function takes in a reference and returns a reference to a the argument passed. this is just example

```
int& function(int& arg)
{
...
 return arg;
}
```

and also here, we can also return a structure by value

```
struct mystruct {
    int foo;
};

struct mystruct function(struct mystruct& arg)
{

  return arg;
}
```

Comment: Thank so so much for this, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The return type doesn't have to always be void. Just like arguments you can return almost anything. you can even return pointers to functions, classes, structures, other primitive types and so on. But you also must follow the rule of the programming language.

Answer (score 1):

The point of passing by reference is that the value can change inside the function, and remains changed for the code after the function call.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.